# OpenBLAS error when importing numpy: `pthread_creat error in blas_thread_init function`

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, openblas

All of a sudden, I cannot import numpy:

```
import numpy as np
OpenBLAS: pthread_creat error in blas_thread_init function. Error code:1
```

I'm running numpy from `Anaconda 1.10.1-py27_0` but I had the same issue on `1.9.3-py27_0`

Any clues?

Edit:Trying to find out what the version used is I did:

```
>ldd multiarray.so
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff53fd4000)
libopenblas.so.0 => not found
libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x00007faa1ec14000)
libpython2.7.so.1.0 => not found
libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007faa1e9f7000)
libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007faa1e663000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000000377fc00000)
```

so it seems that the library is not there.

Comment: Well I didn't even know about it until now, so I guess it was installed with Anaconda. But I haven't changed anything on anaconda, it has just stopped working all of a sudden.

Comment: no such thing as `mkl` on `conda list`, if that says anything..

Comment: Well, there's a number of things. First of all, there's no _dotblass.so under 1.10, but there is under previous versions.

Comment: yep, just installed anaconda and I've done a few conda updates afterwards, as well as updates on specific packages.

Comment: To be honest brute force might be the easiest approach here. I would maybe try uninstalling numpy (check `~/andaconda/pkgs` to make sure it's completely gone) and reinstalling it using conda. If the problem persists, I would then consider removing and reinstalling Anaconda.

Comment: yeah, I'll try that I guess. No idea how this happened though, big mystery. The only thing I've done is to try to install a newer version of tmux, but I don't see how that could ever be related to this issue.

Comment: the ipyhton I'm opening is the Anaconda one. In there, I can import several other modules, but none that depend on numpy. I think Im going to try to do a clean installation

Comment: Did it work for you? Fresh installation? Can you please tell what did you to to get rid of this error? @elelias

Comment: I believe in the end I got a fresh installation. I had been playing around with the packages and started to get this error.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with anaconda. I solved it by updating numpy, scipy and openblas

Comment: you should add how to do that: `machine:user$ conda update numpy scipy openblas`