# Python not working after installing numpy

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Hello my Python bot is running fine but when install `pip3 install numpy` it installs succesfully. but i get errors when i run bot.

```
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable
OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 120 current, 120 max
```

If i uninstall numpy module bot works fine.

Comment: seems like it uses numpy if it finds it, but afterwards there aren't enough resources to run bot with numpy...

Comment: no resources just for a module to run ?

Comment: whn numpy is present, it's probably used. And numpy must use a lot of threads. Probably a limitation of combined usage of both modules on your machine.

Comment: Its running fine in my windows pc but getting error in shared server.

Comment: have you tried to upgrade openblas?

Comment: don't know anything about that.

Comment: Did you install `numpy` using anaconda or pip?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh  installed from `pip3 install numpy`   works fine in local pc and laptop which runs Windows. but error appears only in shared server which is linux after installing numpy.

Comment: You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51257384/6779307) helpful.  You can also upgrade openblas with `pip3 install --upgrade openblas`