# OpenBLAS issue with ComBat() function of the R Bioconductor SVA package on Torque cluster

Tags: r, bioconductor, openblas

I've a problem with [ComBat() function](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sva/versions/3.20.0/topics/ComBat) from the [SVA](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/sva.html) package of Bioconductor in R.

On my laptop (Latitude 5590 running a Linux Ubuntu 18 operating
system), it works well.
But if I ran it on a TORQUE cluster, the call to the ComBat()
function generates an infinite waiting loop:

> "ComBat()"   Found25batches
>
> Note: one batch has only one sample, setting mean.only=TRUE
>
> Adjusting for0covariate(s) or covariate level(s)
>
> Standardizing Data across genes
>
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable
>
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 903725 current, 903725 max
>
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable
>
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 903725 current, 903725 max
>
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable
>
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 903725 current, 903725 max
>
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable
>
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 903725 current, 903725 max
>
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable
>
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: RLIMIT_NPROC 903725 current, 903725 max
>
> OpenBLAS blas_thread_init: pthread_create: Resource temporarily
>   unavailable

Do you know how I can fix it?

I checked online and some people already had [that problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51256738/multiple-instances-of-python-running-simultaneously-limited-to-35?noredirect=1&lq=1), which is related to Python.
That sounds weird to me: if it's a Python problem, why does it show up in R?

Thanks

Comment: It's hard to tell you "the commands / edits to my script to avoid this error and execute my software smoothly" without having any of your script.

Comment: @duckmayr You can find my script here: https://github.com/davidechicco/heart-failure-gene-expression-analysis

Comment: Looks like combat is requesting to use the max number of threads on your machine (fine on your laptop but not on a cluster), as I bet you don't have permission to use all threads on your cluster so it's waiting to get permission but youll never get it. I would look to add a line to combat with number of threads (that you are able to access as a user in a session). This solved my problem a few times when I moved code from a simple machine to a cluster. If not, you're gonna have to talk to your Torque cluster admin.

Comment: Hi @csugai , thanks for your comment. That is possible, but I don't know how to control the number of threads in the script. That's the weird aspect: my script is in R, not in Python, and I see no option for OpenBlas(). Can you please check my code and tell me what you would change? https://github.com/davidechicco/heart-failure-gene-expression-analysis/blob/master/retrieve_genes.r The call to ComBat() is at line #433. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A colleague of mine (outside StackOverflow) helped me and found the solution.

I needed to insert this command in my R script:

`Sys.setenv(OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS="1")`

That was it.